# What is the best way to test for Full Unicode compliance?

Tags: web

We have a web app that needs to support major browsers, as well as major languages. English, Chinese, French etc., hence the full Unicode support. I am wondering how other test engineers go about this?

This will also be stored in a DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTL (right to left) or bi-directionality is a property of the textbox or edit control. The Turkish "i" issue is an common character mapping problem in ANSI encodings or thinking between Unicode and ANSI.

There are several important things to check for Unicode support such as
- Test using Unicode only language families such as the Indic languages
- Test for proper key sequencing and glyph manipulation with Indic, Arabic, Hebrew, etc.
- Test for character clipping with chars in the Thai and Vietnamese languages
- Test for support of surrogate pair characters
- Test input, display, file I/O, and OLE (copy/paste)
- Test appropriate utf encodings (e.g. UTF8, UTF16)
- Although not Unicode, for compliance in China check for GB 18030 support

If general if a character displays as a square it usually means you don't have the proper font installed. If the Unicode characters show up as question marks you are not 100% Unicode enabled. If the Unicode chars turn to garbage then the code is likely converting to ANSI somewhere along the way.

This should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give more details. What language/platform? Is there a database involved? Did you test RTL languages such as Hebrew? Did you take the "Turkey Test":
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html